# Docker exec error "executable file not found in $PATH": unknown" when running a command as a string

Tags: docker

Below is the command I am trying to run:

`docker exec sandbox_1 'influxd-ctl sandbox_1:8091'`

I understand that apparently this means the container will execute it with a different shell that does have the necessary `$PATH` but I'm not sure how to deal with that.

For what it's worth, I tried `influxd-ctl` without the single quotes and it didn't read the rest of the command.

`docker exec sandbox_1 influxd-ctl sandbox_1:8091`

Thoughts?

Update: I also tried running `bash -c <string>` as the command I passed to `exec` but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com/blob/master/content/enterprise_influxdb/v1.3/features/cluster-commands.md#example-1-bind-to-a-remote-meta-node) you are missing parts of the command, like `-bind` or whatever you are trying to do

Comment: Please verify you are replacing `<container>` in your commands. Include an example with real container names, and no quotes.

Comment: @BMitch Happy to do that but that's entirely irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @InDieTasten I can verify that the command (isolated from the Docker issue) is the correct command.

Comment: How are you verifying that the rest of the command isn't being read? If you replaced influxd-ctl with echo as the command to run, does it echo back the arguments?

Comment: @BMitch Good question.  `echo` did return the arguments to `influxd-ctl`.  The reason I thought it wasn't reading the args was that the response I got when not using quotes was the same response you get when you use `influxd-ctl` with no arguments.  It pulled up the `--help` .

Comment: Sounds like you are not running the correct influxd-ctl command. The syntax looks wrong to myself, the first commenter, and apparently to influxd-ctl too if it's giving you a help message.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes shouldn't be used. The [Exec Command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) takes the command and it's arguments as separate arguments.

The correct command in your case should be:

```
docker exec <container> influxd-ctl <container>:8091
```

You can also test the command when having a shell inside the container like this:

```
docker exec -it <container> bash
```

You should then (provided bash is available inside the container, otherwise other shells can be used instead) get a root shell like this:

```
root@<container>:~#
```

Note: The working dir might be different based on where it was set in the Dockerfile used to build the image of the container.

In the now interactive shell talking to the container, you can try your command explicitly without the Exec command passing stuff around.

```
root@<container>:~# influxd-ctl <container>:8091
```

If you find that your command doesn't work there, then probably the influxd-ctl command expects different parameters from what you are suggesting.

Comment: Using no quotes didn't work and is the first thing I tried.  It didn't read the rest of the command (after `influxd-ctl`)